# Running c++ executable file from python console in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, c++, qgis-python-console

I am trying to run a simple c++ program which I have already compiled from python console in QGIS3.32
My goal is to take the output of the C++ program which is nothing but adding 2 numbers, printing the result in the python console.
The c++ script (sample_cpp.cpp) is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    int num1 = 5;
    int num2 = 7;

    int result = add(num1, num2);

    std::cout << "Sum of " << num1 << " and " << num2 << " is: " << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have already compiled this file.
Here is the python code with which I am running the c++ executable :

```
import subprocess
command = ['C:\\Users\\FTL1KOR\\Desktop\\sample_cpp.exe']
result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output = True, text = True)

print('result:', result)
```

Here is the result :

```
exec(Path('C:/Users/FTL1KOR/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpfaa7vt_4').read_text())
result: CompletedProcess(args=['C:\\Users\\FTL1KOR\\Desktop\\sample_cpp.exe'], returncode=3221225595, stdout='', stderr='')
```

But I am unable to get the desired output - which is ***'Sum of 5 and 7 is: 12'***
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is more of a generic Python question than about QGIS/GIS. I'd suggest you ask at https://stackoverflow.com/ instead. Does your exe file work if you run it in a Windows CMD window?

Comment: Yes it runs in Windows CMD properly with the desired output. So I dont think its a python error. Its related to QGIS only. Thats why I tried asking it here.